# Fully charged capacitor is connected to another battery

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, batteries

Suppose an empty capacitor with a capacitance `A Farad` is connected to a `B voltage` battery. After the capacitor is fully charged, the capacitor is disconnected from the battery and then connected to a `C voltage` battery. What would happen to the capacitor at the end? Will the capacitor have a total charge `A(B+C) Coulomb`?

Comment: If the capacitor did have a charge of A(B + C) the voltage between its plates would be (B + C). This wouldn't be the case if it were connected across a battery of emf C.

Comment: Oh, I see. What would happen if C < B? will the charge from the capacitor exit?

Comment: Yes. It's as simple as that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second batterie can charge or discharge A, so the charge will be just $Q=A*C$